# What JavaScript/JQuery syntax is this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have no idea how to search for this so I'm asking here.

I've inherited a project and no one that's here knows what this syntax trick is called.

There's a select drop down change event that will call a function if one or another specific value is selected from among the list.

```
$('#accordion select[name=x_range]').change(function(){
  $('#custom-time')[$(this).val() == 'custom' ? 'show' : 'hide']();
  $('#custom-time-to-now')[$(this).val() == 'custom_to_now' ? 'show' : 'hide']();
  updateTimeIntervalOptions();
}).triggerHandler('change');
```

In this the show or hide function is called on the `#custom-time` or `#custom-time-to-now` divs.

What is calling functions like this called?

EDIT:
I should have said that I understand ternary if/else, but not the `$(selector)[function_name]()` part.

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: IMO, it's silly that they chose to `show/hide` using this obfuscated approach. If they knew of [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), it could **clearly** be written as `$(selector).toggle(condition)`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would say that this is not a trick, but understanding of three features of javascript.

First, functions are first class objects, so you can assign them to variables etc

```
 var f = function () { ... }
 var b = [];
 b[1] = f; // assigning function to array element
 b[1]();   // calling function assigned to array element
```

Second, convenient ternary operator, which is effectively shorthand notation of combination of `if` and assignement:

```
 var a = (b >c ) ? b : c;

 // is the same as

 if (b > c ) {
     a = b;
 } else {
     a = c;
 }
```

And last but not least, is the fact that every object properties can be accessed as dictionary elements, ie

```
 a.b = 5
 a['b'] === 5 // true!
```

So putting all this together you can have expression like this

```
$(selector)[condition?'show':'hide']();
```

Which is equal to

```
if (condition) {
   $(selector).show();
} else {
   $(selector).hide();
}
```

**UPDATE**: One note on this particular case. In most cases you don't need to do complicated stuff like that, as `$().toggle()` accepts boolean argument for toggling on and off, so

```
$(selector)[condition?'show':'hide']();
```

will work the same way as

```
$(selector).toggle(!!condition);
```

Note that I use !! in order to cast value to boolean, as toggle checks paramter using `===`

Answer (score 10):

> What is calling functions like this called?

Poor coding practice.

It's a way to call the `show()` or `hide()` functions dynamically.  It's bloody nasty lookin'.

Edit: apparently my answer is "controversial" to some people.  Please let me clarify: if I can write if-else statements over a ternary operator-- especially for things like string comparisons-- I will definitely take clarity over shorter code.

It's not "bloody nasty lookin'" because of just ternary operators or just bracket access of methods.  It's bloody nasty lookin' because the code took a shortcut over clarity, and took that shortcut when it was not needed.

Ternary operators are not bad.  Bracket access is not bad.  But they are volatile concepts that are easily abused.

Comment: bloody nasty... oh I miss London so much

Comment: i disagree. this is the easiest way to dynamically choose a function to call.

Comment: @jbabey Under some circumstances, yes, it is acceptable to do this.  However, in this case, why not use if-statements?  I always recommend use of if-statements over ternary operators because so many inexperienced programmers equate shorter code with better code.  Overall, this is a poor way to do it because the better way is extremely obvious.

Comment: I disagree as well, it's a perfectly valid method, and even if I agree with the fact that if/else is more readable, doing it with brackets and a ternary is pretty obvious aswell, and I don't think one way is better than the other, and it's definitely not poor coding practice IMO.

Comment: @adeneo I suppose it comes down to a matter of opinion and perhaps experience.  I come from a software engineering background, where coding standards are quite strict.  I always take readability over shortcuts.  Like I said, though, it is acceptable to use bracket access to call functions dynamically in a few situations, but this is definitely not a situation where I would do it.

Comment: @adeneo Sure you can ninja-code like this but it's just saving some characters for the sake of readability...Write a huge application like that and every co-worker will hate you. It's just a matter of clean style. You write code once and read it 10times - why make it unnecessarily hard?

Comment: kevin, I wouldn't necessarily agree.  Ternary definitely has its place.  But its place is to conditionally set the value of one, single variable.  What that variable is used in, after the fact, and the clarity of the code the variable is used in are up to the programmer.  Personally, I'd rather avoid having 18 different sets of interlocking if/elseif/else statements, if I just need to set 18 different variables semi-interdependently.  Especially if they're all in varying degrees of nesting, or in huge stacks.

Comment: This is'nt really ninja-code, it's basic javascript (and many other C like languages), and your co-workers should be able to read basic stuff or keep their noses out of your code.

Comment: @Norguard If I end up 18 sets of if-statements one after another, at that point I'd probably submit my code for review by quality assurance and I'd heavily reconsider my design.

Comment: @Norguard - I don't think the problem is so much the ternary, what gives some people pause is the bracket notation for toggling a function, but I use this all the time, for arrays, functions, you name it, they are all just objects in javascript anyway ?

Comment: I've edited my response.  If it's too controversial to the SO community, then a moderator can lock this thread down, delete my post, or otherwise get buried somehow.  This seems to be a rather subjective topic.  Apologies if I seemed rude.

Comment: @kevin I don't disagree.  But if-statements do a great job of performing multiple operations based on a single valuation.  Ternary-statements do a great job of assigning a single value, based on a single valuation.  If you are setting multiple values based on one result, use an if.  If you are setting multiple values based on multiple results, use ternary.  If you're running ANY functions/routines/yadda-yadda, use if.  And code stays clean and helpful and easy to read.  Also a ternary `method_name` followed by `Obj[method_name]();` is dirt-simple to follow along with, as long as they're clean.

Comment: @adeneo I get that, I think. Really, the big problem is when you start mixing it all together.  I've seen people use called functions inside of ternary return-statements, which will return the function's return value (hopefully a string or a number) into bracket-notation, to call that method...  ...and all of it inline.  Those people need a slap, when it's in production-code.

Comment: @jbabey - It's not the cleanest for showing/hiding a jQuery object: `$(select).toggle(showOrHide)` is *much* more readable.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently it's called [Bracket Notation](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.1)

Answer (score 3):

Ternary operators set values to two or more options (can be nested).

Think of them like a `switch` or an `if/else` or an `if/elseif/.../else` operation, but only for setting ONE value.

So look at something like:

```
var name = X === Y ? "Bob" : "Doug";
sayHello(name);
```

It's a ternary condition which optionally sets the name, based on whether the condition is true or false.

In your jQuery, they're just skipping a step, by using bracket-notation with a ternary inside.

```
People[ (selected_person === "Bob") ? "Bob" : (selected_person === "Doug") ? "Doug" : "Jimmy" ].sayHi();
```

This will call `sayHi()` for `People.Bob`, `People.Doug` or `People.Jimmy`, based on the value of `selected_person`.

So it's a ternary condition used to select an object-property, nested inside of the bracket notation, rather than doing it in two steps:

```
 var person = // ternary from last step
 People[person].sayHi();
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your edit, it's bracket-notation.

```
MyObj = { myFunc : function () { doStuff(); } };
```

You can call `myFunc` in a few different ways.
Either by using dot-notation: `var func = MyObj.myFunc;` or through bracket-notation: `var func = MyObj["myFunc"];`
Either way, the value of `func` is now `myFunc`.

So what they're doing is setting a `string` to the name of the function that they want to call.

`var string = "show";`
`MyObj[string] // = MyObj.show`
`MyObj[string]() // = MyObj.show()`

In the case of your code, they're using ternary to determine the value of the string.

Answer (score 2):

It's called "Array Notation". Look here: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/accessing-jquery-methods-using-array-syntax/

Answer (score 2):

The author is using the ternary operator (`? :`) to call a member function of a jQuery object using array notation, `el['show']()` rather than `el.show()`. Broken down, it would look like:

```
var fnName;
if($(this).val() == 'custom') {
  fnName = 'show';
} else {
  fnName = 'hide';
}

$('#custom-time')[fnName]();  // an alternative to $('#custom-time').show() or .hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this pattern has a specific name. There is a conditional operator that is used to select different method names, then the method is called dynamically using this string with the "bracket" or "array" syntax.